# W/BluetoothGatt: Unhandled exception in callback

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I will explain my problem, I charge a list of BLEs availables an when a find one in concret i do the next

```
gatt = device.connectGatt(MainActivity.this, true, gattCallback);
```

and everything is fine there (or so I think).

But when I run the code below: `gatt.getService(BLOOD_PRESURE_SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(BLOOD_PRESURE_MEASUREMENT_CHAR_UUID);`

I got this error:

> W/BluetoothGatt: Unhandled exception in callback
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID)'
>   on a null object reference

And I have no idea why, the gatt object comes with content, so it is not null, or shouldn't

```
BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
@Override
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
   super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
   if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){
      gatt.discoverServices();
   }
}

@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
   super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
   BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
      gatt.getService(BLOOD_PRESURE_SERVICE_UUID)
         .getCharacteristic(BLOOD_PRESURE_MEASUREMENT_CHAR_UUID);
   gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

   BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor =
      characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID);

   descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
   gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
 }
};
```

I have read, in another entry that a person happened that the CallBack was empty and that's why the error jumped. This user comments on the solution they provide, [Unhandled exception in callback while trying to connect with BluetoothGatt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632855/unhandled-exception-in-callback-while-trying-to-connect-with-bluetoothgatt#comment68499343_40633482)
But if this is my case, I don't know how to solve it.

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you try to call `getCharacteristic` on is null. That means `gatt.getService(BLOOD_PRESURE_SERVICE_UUID)` returned null. That means the device you connected to doesn't have the blood pressure gatt service. (And you misspelled pressure...)